# AutoMapper Condition based on property name

Tags: c#, automapper

With the following mapping I am able to selectively choose which property values to map based on their values.

```
config
  .CreateMap<SourceAddress, DestinationAddress>()
  .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((s, d, sv, dv, rc) => true));
```

How would I go about making this decision based on the property metadata, like its name or attributes applied to it?

Note that when I break in the implementation of the condition delegate, the `ResolutionContext` parameter `rc` has both `InstanceCache` and `Items` empty.

Comment: Maybe you should give an example of what you're trying to achieve. This is kind of vague.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear. I was asking what @Timothy Ghanem answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper does allow [Global property/field filtering](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#global-propertyfield-filtering). So you can try using this in your `MapperConfiguration`:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ShouldMapProperty = pi =>
    {
        return true;
    };
});
```